# Error while removing Java on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7

I'm trying to uninstall Java from Windows 7.

> ERROR 1723.There is a problem with this windows installer package.A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run.Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

Comment: Try to restart you computer, then try again. If problems remains try to *install* the same version of java again and then uninstall it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-1723-there-is-a-problem-with-this-windows/fbd2f290-25e8-4199-81f1-3a94791ac9a8):

> Try to remove Java using Windows Cleanup utility. Click [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) for a link to the Windows Installer Cleanup Tool. 
>   You can use the utility to remove installation information for programs that were installed by using Windows Installer. Be aware that Windows Installer CleanUp Utility will not remove the actual program from your computer. However, it will remove the installation files so that you can start the installation, upgrade, or uninstall over.
>
> After it is removed, restart your computer and then try to install the latest version Java. If this fails, contact Java for further support. [www.java.com](http://www.java.com)
>   You might also look at [this article](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.xml) from Java.

Comment: Its working better now